# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.0.1

Tags: maven, dependencies

Here is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>test3</groupId>
<artifactId>test3</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

The dependencies junit, and org.apache.poi both work, I havn't added any jars to the class path to get them to work either, I believe maven downloaded them just from the pom, my code is also working.
However when I add the org.seleniumhq.selenium dependency I get the error "Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.0.1" and I am unable to use any classes from webdriver.

Why would it just be this dependency that is not working? What could I try to fix this? I have been scouring stackoverflow and other resources to try and get this to work, any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was adding dependency for selenium-java-3.0.1.jar, but when I included my 'settings.xml' file path in Global Settings option under 'Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings' in eclipse, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was outdated password for proxy. Check your ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Delete any existing folders for selenium in .m2 folder and try to save the pom.xml again.

Answer (score 0):

Set your setting.xml file path in your Global Settings and click on apply and then click on apply and close button
(Setting.xml file path) -> C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.1\conf\settings.xml

This problem will be solved